# JavaFX, Maven - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:sampleDB;create=true

Tags: maven, javafx, derby, javadb

Using JavaFX and Maven, I get this error when I run the external jar file and attempting to connect to my database:
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:sampleDB;create=true"

My database class:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvvcu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the driver before you can connect the database:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
```

Or if you are using the Derby Embedded:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
```

Comment: Thank! Worked for me!